# which JS file need to building responsive web?

Tags: html, responsive-design

I'm tring to build a website which is responsive web and markup with `HTML5` & `CSS3`.

the question is.. which JS file do i need to use for IE 7-9 to show perfectly?

for now, I'm going to use....

http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js

http://css3pie.com/

is this sufficient for IE 7-9  ?

Comment: How about responsive frameworks like "bootstrap" or "foundation 4"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

html5shiv.js gives you the possibility to style markup elements that were introduced in HTML5 like `<article>`, `<section>`, `<header>` etc. It's crucial to enable styling these elements in old IE.

However the fundamental technique in responsive web design are media queries, which also aren't supported in older versions of IE. For this you'd need to add [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) and I think you're off to a good start.

Css3pie is a nice tool, but not required, depending on your design. If you're not going to use CSS gradients, box-shadow or border-radius you may not need it. I think it would be best to plug it into a finished website if necessary.

Starting with a front-end framework, as suggested by 蒋艾伦, is also a good suggestion.